# Paginating a list based on page count and page id in java

Tags: java, list, pagination

I have a list say its has 25 rows. My page count will be always 5 and i ll be passing the pageId to the list so that i can get only those 5 rows which belongs to that page id (say if my pageId is 2 i need rows from 6-10).. Any simple method to do this???

`List<Employee> empList= (List<Employee>)employeeHelper.fetchallData();`

This `emplist` will have all the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand, but it seems you are looking for a sublist of `emplist`.

You can use the method [`List.subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) for it.

From the javadocs:

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified
>   fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and
>   toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is
>   backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list
>   are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports
>   all of the optional list operations supported by this list.
>
> This method eliminates the need for explicit range operations (of the
>   sort that commonly exist for arrays). Any operation that expects a
>   list can be used as a range operation by passing a subList view
>   instead of a whole list.

To get the elements 5-10 (inclusive, count start at 1) in the 2nd doc:
`emplist.subList(25 * (2-1) + (5-1), 25 * (2-1) + 10)`

Comment: Yes, `list.subList(pageIndex * pageCount, (pageIndex + 1) * pageCount);`